# Add the bars difference values on the top of each bar groups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a group bar plot that shows three different metrics for two algorithms. [image: summary plot]

How can I add the percentage of increase/decrease between this two different algorithms on the top of each bar? For example, on the top of the precision bar, we should have -0.017 and for the coverage bar we should have +0.3867 on the top.

Here is my R code:

```
als_precision<-0.27069
als_ndcg<-0.1523
als_coverage<-362/3233

als_reg_precision<-0.2659
als_reg_ndcg<-0.1520
als_reg_coverage<-502/3233


barplot(matrix(c(als_precision,als_reg_precision,als_ndcg,als_reg_ndcg,als_coverage,als_reg_coverage),nr=2), beside=T, 
        col=c("red","blue"), 
        names.arg=c("Precision@10","NDCG@10","coverage"))
legend("topright", c("ALS","ALS+reg"), pch=15, 
       col=c("red","blue"), 
       bty="n")
```

Comment: As text? Take a look at `text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text` to add the text to the plot.

**Edit**  The original did not use the *percentage* change.

```
barplot(matrix(c(als_precision,als_reg_precision,als_ndcg,als_reg_ndcg,
        als_coverage,als_reg_coverage),nr=2), beside=T, 
        col=c("red","blue"), ylim=c(0,0.30),
        names.arg=c("Precision@10","NDCG@10","coverage"))
legend("topright", c("ALS","ALS+reg"), pch=15, 
       col=c("red","blue"), 
       bty="n")

text(2, max(als_precision, als_reg_precision)+0.01, 
    round((als_reg_precision - als_precision)/als_precision,3))

text(5, max(als_ndcg, als_reg_ndcg)+0.01, 
    round((als_reg_ndcg - als_ndcg)/als_ndcg,3))

text(8, max(als_coverage, als_reg_coverage)+0.01, 
    round((als_reg_coverage - als_coverage)/als_coverage,3))
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: What is the reason for all those max, min calculations?

Comment: Only one max per text statement was needed.  I misunderstood the question.  The remaining max is there to be above the _highest_ bar.

Comment: Thanks. How do add those texts without calculations? For example, I may want to "+0.37" as a text.

Comment: Take a look at the help on text  `?text`.  The arguments are   `text(x_coord, y_coord, label)`.  You can put whatever you want as the label.

Comment: The first label is not shown. So, there is no -0.018 on the precision@10 bar

Comment: I just checked. That is the code that I used to make the chart and my chart shows the -0.018.  Also retested by cutting and pasting from the answer.  Works for me.